# How to automatically populate and update a lookup column based on a condition on sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, microsoft-flow

I have 2 lists:

List A:

[image]

List B:

[image]

I want to extract all the Projects from List A and display them in ProjectsList column in List B where:
LinkTitle(List B) = Company (List A)

At the end, I want the column ProjectsList in List B to automatically populate and update whenever there is a new entry or an update or a delete in List A, and I want List B to look something like this:

[image]

I tried to make the column 'ProjectsList' in List B a lookup column, which looks up the column company in List A, but it is only giving me the list of all the Companies present in List A and I have to manually enter them.

I also tried creating a flow but it is not working.
My Flow:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help me out with this? Any solution other than flow would also work for me if its giving the desired output.